# How to hide GET requests from also being displayed on web

Tags: python, django, http, python-requests, django-urls

So I'm working on a django project, and one of the objectives is to allow a separate python script to make a HTTP request (using Requests library) to get json data **after** being authenticated. This works fine, the problem is that if I directly go the url the request.get object uses, I can see all of the data (without any user authentication being involved). This makes my authentication process pointless, as the data is easily visible by simply going to the url. So how would I hide the data on the web side from being viewed, but still allow a GET request to pull the data to my script?

On a side note, I already have a authentication system for the web interface portion of my project (which displays the data). I've tried putting it behind that but to no success.

```
import json, requests, _mysql
login_attempt = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/m_app/data_login/', 
{'username': 'test', 'password': 'password1234'})
if login_attempt.content.decode('UTF-8') == 'Successful':
    print('Logged in.')
else:
    print('Not logged in.')
cookies = dict(sessionid=login_attempt.cookies.get('sessionid'))
data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/m_app/load/data', #if I type this URL in, I see the data 
cookies=cookies)
print(data.content) #prints desired data
```

Comment: see this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all your views in django are public, but it's easy to make them protected by [checking `request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-raw-way) or [using a `login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).